# Android action bar navigation

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've got spinner navigation on my action bar and have a navigation listener for this.
When the activity is created the listener (below) picks up on the default spinner item which means case 0 is run on creation, opening another activity. 
How do I stop it registering a navigation change when the activity is created?

```
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
            switch(itemPosition) {
            case 0:

                Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Example.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent i2 = new Intent(Main.this, Example.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Main.this, Example.class);
                startActivity(i3);
                break;
            case 3:
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Main.this, Example.class);
                startActivity(i4);
                break;
            }
        return false;
    }
    };
```

**Update:**
Think I solved it with this, I declared a boolean flag, changed it to false oncreate.

```
ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        switch(itemPosition) {
        case 0:
            if(flag == true) {
                if(Main.class == Main.class) {

                } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Main.class);
            startActivity(i);   
                }
            }
            if(flag == false) {
                flag = true;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent i2 = new Intent(Main.this, Example.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent i3 = new Intent(Main.this, Example.class);
            startActivity(i3);
            break;
        case 3:
            Intent i4 = new Intent(Main.this, Example.class);
            startActivity(i4);
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a simpler way but you could put a `boolean` flag in `onCreate()` to false and check for that in your listener then set it to true after the first time when it sets up so it won't run the `Intent` code when you first run it. Depending on what you need, you may want to put it in `onResume()` so it doesn't run if you back into this `Activity`